# a.s. convergence in $\ell_2$ space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Assume $(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of random variables defined on the same probability space and taking values at $\ell_{2}$ (space of square-summable sequences). Next, assume that for some $a\in \ell_{2}$
$$
\sqrt{n}(X_{n} - a) \xrightarrow{a.s.} Z,
$$
where $Z$ is a random variable.

Is this true that
$$
X_{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} a?
$$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining
$$
  Y_n= \sqrt n(X_n-a) - Z,
  $$
we have
by hypothesis that $Y_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$, so
$$
X_n=\frac{Z + Y_n}{\sqrt n}+a \xrightarrow{n\to0} a.
$$

Comment: could you, please, clarify it...

Comment: Yes, but it would be nice to know exactly which part you failed to understand.

Comment: I do not understand "By hypothesis $\sqrt n(X_n-a) = Z + Y_n$".

Comment: Note, I added that $Z$ is random.

Comment: Just define $Y_n =\sqrt n(X_n-a) - Z$.

Comment: hm... I would rather write then simply $X_n=\frac{Z}{\sqrt n}+a,$ then, note that $\ell_{2}$ is separable, then $\frac{Z}{\sqrt n}$ goes to zero a.s. Why do we need one more variable?

Comment: What you wrote is not true.

Comment: oh.. I see now.... then, it would be better if you write this in your answer

Comment: Is it more clear now?